# JQuery. Не срабатывает клик по кнопке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть кнопка с id closeEdit и есть событие, которое должно срабатывать при клике, но оно не срабатывает:

```
      $("#closeEdit").click(function () {
        $("#inEdit").text($("#editText").val());
      })
```

Как это исправить?

(думал, что .text() не сработал, проверил `alert`'ом, не сработало)

Comment: код рабочий, вероятно ваш `#closeEdit` отсутствует во время инициализации этого кода...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятно, во время инициализации вашего кода, элементы, задействованные в коде, отсутствуют в `DOM`.

Оберните ваш код в [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Код, включенный в `$(document).ready()` будет запускаться только после того, как объектная модель документа (`DOM`) страницы будет готова для JavaScript.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#closeEdit").click(function() {
    $("#inEdit").text($("#editText").val());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="closeEdit">Нажми меня</button>
<input id="editText" value="Текст из поля" />
<div id="inEdit"></div>
```

Также вы можете использовать функцию [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) и тогда вам фактически не нужно использовать функцию готовности документа(указанную выше).

```js
$(document).on('click', '#closeEdit', function() {
  $("#inEdit").text($("#editText").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="closeEdit">Нажми меня</button>
<input id="editText" value="Текст из input" />
<div id="inEdit"></div>
```